# Please help me identify this tree with irregular leaves

Tags: identification, trees

I found this tree growing on a farm on the outskirts of Johannesburg, South Africa.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

p.s. The pink fabric is not part of the tree :p

Comment: Could be a type of pepper tree, which is a weed. I am not sure though.

Comment: I don't think it's a pepper tree. I could not see any seeds or berries on the ground around it, and none on the tree either. Does that necessarily rule out pepper tree?

Comment: I am not sure, I don't think they produce berries all year round so perhaps it could still be.

Comment: It is late summer here. I'm quite certain that if there were berries on this tree, that there would be some trace of them around and on it. I have seen some trees here that I know to be pepper trees, and there is always some trace of their fruit.

Answer (score 3):

I do believe this to be Melia azedarach, also known as Chinaberry or Bead Tree. (Not to be confused with Azadirachta indica as so many Google images appear to portray).

A photo of flowers or fruits could help confirm.

http://blog.growingwithscience.com/2012/09/seed-of-the-week-chinaberry/

http://research.pomona.edu/bfs/2012/11/05/new-bfs-plant-melia-azedarach-chinaberry/